# Ruby/Rails: How do I allow whitespace, dash and ÄÖÜ in my regex?

Tags: ruby, regex

Currently my regular Expression looks like this: `/\A[a-zA-Z]{2,50}\z/i`

Now I would like to add acceptance of: `-`, `whitespace` and `ÄÖÜ`.

I tried rubular.com but I'm a total regex noob.

Comment: Read about [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add it in the regex as follows:

```
/\A[a-zA-Z\-\sÄÖÜ]{2,50}\z/i
```

[**DEMO**](http://rubular.com/r/LhKeDQa2Un)

`regex` is an invaluable cross-language tool that the sooner you learn, the better off you will be. I suggest putting in the time to [**learn it**](http://regexone.com/)

Comment: This assumes your source file has an encoding that accepts äöüÄÖÜ, but that should be standard nowadays. You may add whatever characters you like to your character match (which is the thing enclosed in square brackets).

Answer (score 4):

Probably you want to think about using [Unicode properties and scripts](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html). You could write your regex then as

```
\A[\p{L}\s-]{2,50}\z
```

See it [here on Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/lc0wP65AQM)

`\p{L}` is a Unicode property and matching any letter in any language.

If you want to match ÄÖÜ you maybe also want ß, using Unicode properties you don't have to think about such things.

If you want to limit the possible letters a bit you can use a Unicode script such as Latin

```
\A[\p{Latin}\s-]{2,50}\z
```

[See it on Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/i0baDoCAOq)

Answer (score 1):

In a regex, whitespace is represented by the shorthand character class `\s`.
A hyphen/minus is a special character, so must be escaped by a backslash `\-`
Ä, Ö and Ü are normal characters, so you can just add them as they are.

```
/\A[a-zA-Z\s\-ÄÖÜ]{2,50}\z/i
```